# PHP find a specific file in directories listed

Tags: php, include

I am making an article system and I need to `include` all articles in directories listed in a directory. Example:

- Find directories in directory "articles"
- Find files called "article.php" in directories in the directory "articles"
- include files called "article.php"

As I am new to PHP I don't know how to do this. All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for you:

```
$base_dir = './articles';
$filename = 'article.php';

// Listing all directories in $base_dir
$directories = scandir($base_dir);

// Looping over the directories
foreach($directories as $directory) {
  if (! in_array($directory, array('.', '..'))) {

    $filepath = $base_dir.'/'.$directory.'/'.$filename;

    // if the file exists, we include it
    if (is_file($filepath)) {
      include_once($filepath);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty...

```
$data = '';
$dir = "path_to_your_articles";
$dirHandle = opendir($dir);
$lookForThis = 'article.php';
while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
  if(!is_dir($file)){
    if($file == $lookForThis){
      $data .= $file;
    }
  }
}
closedir($dirHandle);
echo $data;
```

Hope this is of some use...